AWS Cloudwatch Explorer Widget shows No Data Available for custom metrics
I am exporting disk and memory metrics on via cloudwatch agent for my autoscaling groups via following user data
yum update -y

yum install -y amazon-cloudwatch-agent

mkdir -p /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc

echo '{
  "agent": {
    "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
    "run_as_user": "root"
  },
  "metrics": {
    "append_dimensions": {
      "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
      "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
    },
    "metrics_collected": {
      "mem": {
        "measurement": [
          "mem_used_percent"
        ],
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60
      },
      "disk": {
        "measurement": [
          "disk_used_percent"
        ],
        "resources": [
          "/"
        ],
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60
      }
    }
  }
}' > /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json

/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl \
  -a fetch-config \
  -m ec2 \
  -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json \
  -s

The metrics are in cloudwatch via the CWAgent Namespace and i can visualise them via Browse Pannels.
I am trying to add a empty Explorer widget with my custom metric but it shows No Data Available as shown below

Should anything else be configured?

Have you tried checking CloudWatch Agent Logs?  can probably be found here: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log

metrics are in cloudwtach and i can visualise them via Line Widget > Browse, the problem is that they somehow are not displayed in the Explorer Widget

try changing the aggregation types or timestamp maybe?

Via user data, I would append some parameters (including the auto-scaling group name). However, Explorer recognizes this parameter as a tag, not as a dimension. Therefore, I completely removed it from the user data. Now, we can use Explorer to visualize the historical user data dynamically through explorer
